# Adding custom handler to specific API wso2 API-Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to add a custom handler and APIAuthenticationHandler to a specific API and it needs to be added below the

handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>

(Note that APIAuthenticationHandler is called twice here, it's a custom requirement)

How can I do this programmatically by editing the velocity_template.xml

I'm using API-Manager 2.00

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [API custom properties](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Custom+Properties+to+APIs) for this. Add a custom property (e.g. `auth_mode=Inhouse`) to the API and then based on that, update the handler section in the velocity template like this.

```
<Handlers>
    #foreach($handler in $handlers)
        #if(($handler.className ==
"org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler") &&
($apiObj.additionalProperties.get('auth_mode') == "Inhouse"))
            <handler xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" class="$handler.className">
            #if($handler.hasProperties())
                #set ($map = $handler.getProperties())
                #foreach($property in $map.entrySet())
                    <property name="$!property.key" value="$!property.value"/>
                #end
            #end
            </handler>
            <handler class="org.wso2.apim.custom.extensions.CustomAuthHandler"/>
<Handlers>
```

If you can't use custom properties, you can use `$!apiName` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am using APIM 2.0.0 it does not have the feature to add a custom property, Also I need to add the custom handler right below the APIAuthenticationHandler

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution worked for me. I used $apiName to match specific API.

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

if ($!apiName.toLowerCase().endsWith("basic"))
         
    #else